# How to change Blog post layout via Powershell in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, blog

This is the option that I want to change via Powershell

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to Robert's answer, which is correct for SharePoint online environment , if you have 2013 On Premise environment, you can use the below code:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "https://sharepoint/sites/blog"
write-host $web.Properties["ms-blogs-skinid"]
$web.Properties["ms-blogs-skinid"] = 1
$web.Properties.update()
```

Valid values for ms-blogs-skinid: 0,1,2

Also, in case its SharePoint online and you dont want to use PnP, use it as below:

```
$SiteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/blog"
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credential.UserName, $credential.Password)
$web = $context.Site.RootWeb
$props =  $web.AllProperties
$web.AllProperties["ms-blogs-skinid"] = "0";  # use 1 or 2 based on your requirement 
$web.Update()
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been looking for an answer for quite a while now.

Comment: welcome ! Glad i could help :)

Comment: actually, my solution works just fine on premises also, just donwload the correct MSI: SharePointPnPPowerShell2013.msi

Answer (score 2):

First install the Dev PnP Powershell tools:

https://github.com/officedev/PnP-PowerShell

Choose the correct MSI for your environment:

- SharePoint 2013 on Premise: SharePointPnPPowerShell2013.msi
- SharePoint 2016 on Premise: SharePointPnPPowerShell2016.msi
- SharePoint 2013 online: SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline.msi

Then use the following Powershell commands (don't forget to fill in the correct values for the two variables in the first two lines of the script):

```
$SitecollectionUrl = "https://yourhostname/sites/test"
$RelativePathToBlogSite = "/sites/test/blog"

connect-sponline $SitecollectionUrl
$web = get-pnpweb $RelativePathToBlogSite
Set-PnPPropertyBagValue -web $web -key ms-blogs-skinid -Value 1
```

Values:

- 0 = Basic
- 1 = Boxed
- 2 = Inline

Comment: Thanks! I will keep this in mind while moving to SharePoint Online.

Comment: this works just fine on SharePoint on Premises too. Just download the On premises version of the tools: SharePointPnPPowerShell2013.msi

Comment: Sure i will take a look.

Comment: I can recommend it, it's very powerful and basically the only tool I ever use nowadays for doing Powershell with SharePoint